# Developer to Production Cashe

Tags: magento2, model, developer-mode, production-mode

I have been using MAGE for about 2 months now and I am a Neophyte to front and back end. I am looking for a little guidance in changing form "developer" to "production" mode. I don't use the CL, I use a combo of my FTP access and CMS.

1. What is the order of changing modes?
2. What cashe folders do I delete?

I changed modes by going to:

1. app/etc/ and opening env.php
2. then I changed MAGE_MODE' => 'developer' to MAGE_MODE' => 'production'

I have read that I have to delete the files in the cash folders.

1. What should I do first? Delete cashe or change modes?
2. Which folders and which files should I clear from what file paths?(In the examples I have seen the file structure is different from mine).

I have read a few articles and posts on when to use which mode but I am still a little unclear. Could you give me examples of what mode to use for what?

1. Developer mode: What tasks should I do in this mode?
2. Production mode: What tasks should I do in this mode?

I hope this is not too tall an order to ask. So please forgive my newness to Magento.

Comment: I did find this link that explains the Mode differences: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: I also found this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html . I guess it is a matter of finding the folders but files are not in the same place.

Comment: I found this...                                                                                                                       1. sudo php bin/magento maintenance:disable
2. clear cache
3. sudo chmod 777 var* -R
4. sudo chmod 777 pub* -R                                                                                                   #2 says** clear Cashe  ** : Where and what are the names of the cashe I should clear?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research and taking chances with the back-end by renaming folders to find my way, I answered a few of my questions. This is what worked for me. Hopefully this can help you.

In my research I have found very different background layouts. **I offer this as a log of what worked for me, nothing more**.

What is the order of changing modes?

1. I **deleted** my cache folders first. **var/cache** and **var/page_cache**
2. I **remade** both folders with their same names in the original folder they were in.
3. **Found** file: app/etc/env.php
4. **found** the code line MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'
5. Then **changed** it to MAGE_MODE' => 'production'
6. Then I **saved** the file in the same folder.
7. I logged out
8. Then logged back in.

As far as my last 2 questions I did not found a succinct list of things that should be done in either of the 2 modes. However, I did get a feel for what they are for.

- Developer mode: What tasks should I do in this mode? Anything that builds the structure of the site. Any kind of app or theme development. It sounded like you don't ever have to be in this mode.
- Production mode: What tasks should I do in this mode? This mode is for content building and general site behavior. It sounded like you use this 90% of the time.

I arrived at the these answers after 4 hours of research and conversing with a Siteground Magento2.2.4  representative.

Again thank you so much for letting me pose these questions to the community. This is what worked for me. Please remember this is a log based on my experience. Hope it helps.